# Magento: How can I have a “debug flag” in my Magento Extension?

Tags: php, debugging, magento

I'd like to have a debug flag in the Magento extension that I'm developing. I'd like to have it set to true when I develop and when I release the extension to users have it removed (defaulting to false). What is the best way to implement this?

The first thing that comes to mind is to have this flag default to false and set it to true in my app/etc/local.xml file. But how can I introduce a new XML node into local.xml and have the Magento infrastructure parse if for me and make it available to my PHP code? Are there other, easier approaches to this?

Comment: No offense, but please modify your question to make more clear what you want to achieve exactly. After reading your question it looked like the debug flag should be distributed anyway. In your own answer you are contradicting the question by don't wanting to have the debug flag to be distributed at all. Makes people wasting their time ^^

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen - None taken. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've rephrased the question as you requested, though a little too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento ECG gave me a good solution in the Magento forums: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/226496/

Quoting them:

> One of the solutions to set and get
>   debug flag in your module is to add it
>   to config.xml in your module’s etc
>   directory.
>
> You can add it to section .
>   So your section will look like:
>
> ```
> <default>
>     <your_module>
>         <debug>1</debug>     
>     </your_module> 
> </default>
> ```
>
> And from the code you can get this:
>
> `$debugFlag = Mage::getStoreConfig('your_module/debug');`

And what I'm going to do is put the same XML block in my local.xml file. That way it only kicks in on my development machine and does not get published with my Magento extension (as does the extension's own config.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Make it configurable through the admin panel, and set it to false by default. If it's in the code a user could toggle it anyway, so you may as well put it in the developer section of the settings panel.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `admin/system/config` of Magento for this.

Add an appropriate `etc/system.xml` to your module, e.g.:

```
<config>
    <!-- : -->
    <tabs>
        <!-- : -->
        <mycompany>
            <label>My Company Tab</label>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
        </mycompany>
        <!-- : -->
    </tabs>
    <!-- : -->
    <sections>
        <!-- : -->
        <mymodule>
            <label>My Module</label>
            <tab>mycompany</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <mygroup>
                    <label>My Group</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <debug>
                            <label>Debug</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </debug>
                    </fields>
                </mygroup>
            </groups>
        </mymodule>
        <!-- : -->
    </sections>
</config>
```

If the section `mymodule` didn't already exist before, you also need to define access control for the module initially (must be put into `etc/config.xml` of your module):

```
</config>
    <!-- : -->
    <adminhtml>
        <!-- : -->
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <mymodule >
                                            <title>My Module</title>
                                        </mymodule>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <!-- : -->
    </adminhtml>
    <!-- : -->
</config>
```

Now admins can change the defined debug flag thru the Magento backend by selecting

`System -> Configuration` - `My Module` - `My Group` - `Debug` - `Yes|No`

To get the current value of your debug flag programmatically you can use:

```
$sFlag = Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule/mygroup/debug');     // null | '0' | '1'
$bFlag = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('mymodule/mygroup/debug'); // true | false
```